# decrypt password in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, encryption, mcrypt

I'd like to prepare a simple script for connecting to some VPN network. The password to the network consists of two elements: pretty complicated pass + randomized token. I don't want to remember this password but store it encrypted in some secure directory. Now, the script I need should ask me for a passphrase and some token, read decrypt a pass from a file and run some commands. All those are pretty easy except one thing: is it possible to decrypt a file to a variable instead of file? I mean I'd like to get something like

```
PASS=`mdecrypt password.nc`
```

but as far as I know mdecrypt generates a file as a result instead of returning value. I know I could run something like

```
`mdecrypt password.nc`
PASS=`cat password`
`unlink password`
```

but is there some easier (one liner) solution?

Answer (score 1):

uset the `-F` option

`-F` Force output on standard output or input from stdin if that is a
              terminal.   By  default mcrypt will not output encrypted data to
              terminal

Comment: Didn't help: `mdecrypt iweb_pass.nc -F
mdecrypt: iweb_pass already exists; do you wish to overwrite (y or n)?y
Enter passphrase: 
File iweb_pass.nc was decrypted.`

Comment: But the file name I specified is in fact where I store encrypted data -  otherwise how mdecrypt will determine what should it decrypt?